# MOXy: inheritance and lists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jaxb, moxy

I'm using MOXy 2.5.1 along with Jersey 2.4 and Hibernate.  I'm seeing a strange marshalling behavior with MOXy with a specific set of classes.

I have classes that look similar to this (with additional stuff removed for brevity):

```
public abstract class ListWrapper<M> {
    protected List<M> records = new ArrayList<M>();
    public abstract List<M> getRecords();
    // plus functions to make it look like a List / Iterator
}

public abstract class RecordList<T extends Record> extends ListWrapper<T> {
    protected Person person;
    @XmlElement
    public Person getPerson() { return person; }
}

public class FooList extends RecordList<Foo> {
    @Override
    @XmlElement(type=Foo.class)
    public List<Foo> getRecords() { return super.records; }
}

public class Holder {
    @XmlElement
    public FooList getFooList() { /* ... */ }
}
```

When `Holder` gets marshalled to XML using MOXy I get the following:

```
<holder>
    <fooList>
        <records>...</records>
        <records>...</records>
        <person>...</person>
    </fooList>
</holder>
```

I was expecting those `<records>` elements to be named `<foos>` instead.

If I put a `name="foos"` entry on the `@XmlElement` declaration in `FooList` I will get my expected name, but then MOXy does something else that's a bit strange.  It will still output elements named `<records>` within the `<fooList>` element, but these `<records>` will only contain the `<id>` values for the (Hibernate) database entries that these correspond to.  And so it looks like this:

```
<holder>
    <fooList>
        <records><id>5</id></records>
        <records><id>10</id></records>
        <person>...</person>
        <foos>...</foos>
        <foos>...</foos>
    </fooList>
</holder>
```

It doesn't matter if I use an `@XmlElementWrapper`, a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`, or any other thing I can think of.  I will either get the wrong names, or a second set of elements that contain a limited set of data.  It's almost as though MOXy is not understanding the inheritance structure here or something.

I'll play around with a few other things in the meantime (e.g. `ListWrapper` API; it's not my design), but to me this looks like a bug in MOXy.  Note that the same behaviors happen with JSON, so this isn't limited to XML.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  I simply put `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` on the `ListWrapper` and `RecordList` classes (it was already on the `FooList` class in my code).  I think MOXy is (incorrectly?) looking up the tree to `ListWrapper` and creating an output entry based on that.